# How to include ApplicationUser in a relational table/model in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I attempting to create a relational table between the `ApplicationUser` and a table I've added `Step`.

I think I'm a little confused about what `ApplicationUser` is verse `IdentityUser` verse the `UserManager`, etc.

This is my attempt at the model.

```
public class UserStep
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int UserStepID { get; set; }
    public int StepID { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual Step Step { get; set; }
}
```

I've adjusted my model based on new information, however I still don't know if this is correct.  I can pull an index of the usersteps with this:

```
    var userSteps = db.UserSteps.Include(u => u.Step).Include(u => u.User);
    return View(userSteps.ToList());
```

However my goal is to show only the steps associated to the current user.  Any suggestions on how to change this to return only the current user?

**Update**

Within the controller for userstep, I have added this new method and created a view from it(which blows up).  My goal is to get a list of usersteps associated to the current user.  Is this not what you described in your update 2?

```
public ActionResult UserStep()
{
    var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var userStepsList = db.UserSteps.Where(u => u.UserId == user.Id);
    return View(userStepsList);

}
```

**Updated - Working Version**

ApplicationUser Model in IdentityModel

Added

```
public virtual ICollection<UserStep> UserSteps { get; set; }
```

UserStep Model

```
public class UserStep
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int UserStepID { get; set; }
    public int StepID { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual Step Step { get; set; }


}
```

Step Model

Added

```
public virtual ICollection<UserStep> UserSteps { get; set; }
```

Created userstep controller and created a new method to view user specific relational table.

```
  public ActionResult UserStep()
{
    var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var userStepsList = db.UserSteps.Where(u => u.UserId == user.Id).Include(u => u.Step).Include(u => u.User);
    return View(userStepsList);

}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of UserStepId? If UserStep a join table then you don't need UserStepId

Comment: There may be multiple usersteps however.  for example, many steps for one user.  I have adjusted my code above based on new information.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Kyle - I added an update based off of your suggestion, but I feel I may be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the Step object directly to the ApplicationUser model as an extension.

If you open up IdentityModel.cs you can add properties like so:

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser 
  {
      public virtual ICollection<Step> UserSteps { get; set; }

      public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> blah blah
      {
           blah
      }
  }
```

Add an ID to the child object (referencing to the parent) if I were you, I would make the ApplicationUser the parent (meaning an ApplicationUser has one or many UserSteps) by adding the property `public int UserId{get;set;}` so that when you need to get a particular users UserStep you can do so by querying the db.Steps with the User's ID.

Hope this helps, comment with questions I'll try and check back tomorrow early.

**Update 1:**

The way you have the user reference to ApplicationUser is close to what you are going to want to add to Step. Make it look more like this though...(in your Step object)

```
public int UserID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserID")]
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

I noticed your [ForeignKey("")] declarations were different from how I impliment mine, I'm not sure if your way is wrong, however I know my way works for me (having the [ForeignKey()] on the navigation property, not the actual model property)

I remember my first relationship with applicationuser was really tricky, but it's so important and gratifying when you get it.

**Update 2**

In response to your comment...

You will grab a reference to a user by something like :

```
var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id = parameterID)
```

parameterID being the id passed to whatever ActionResult you have GETing your collection of UserSteps. If you wanted to just get the current Users ID, try something like:

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Then you just query for the list of userSteps from that User's ID

```
var userSteps = db.UserSteps.Where(u => u.UserID == user.Id)
```

you could then return View(userSteps) if you have a view directly binding for a list of UserStep objects (which is how I would display these if I were you).

Hope this works out for you, I'll check back again later.

Comment: Thanks guys.  It seems much closer.  I have been able to scaffold some views and can manually add the relation and then view a list of all relations.  I did get one aspect working before your comment where I have - public virtual ICollection<UserStep> UserSteps { get; set; } in my appuser model instead of what you listed.  Would you be able to explain the difference?  Additionally, while I'm beginning to understand how these relationships are made now, I'm still confused about how to view only the users steps for one user.  Would you be able to respond to my 2nd section of code above?

Comment: The List was actually a typo by me, I appologize, ICollection will work just fine keep it that way.

Comment: Thanks Kyle.  It was more the <UserStep> vs yours of <Step>. will that change the way the functionality works for the better?  I'm still getting a few errors but I hope to spend some more time on this later today.  Thaks again for the help and I agree, this just seems like such an important hole to fill in my knowledge.

Comment: this resource is good for learning how to establish different relationships http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx just establish this with ApplicationUser and Step (1 Application user can have many steps)

Comment: I would omit the join table completely and design the Step Object to belong to a user, and allow the user to have multiple step objects through an Icollection<Step> I would not use the model UserStep since that is represented by the ICollection<Step>.

Comment: The reason the step is not owned by the user is because the user should only be allowed to view a step.  The admin will then be able to create steps, edit, delete, etc.  The reason for the join table is that I'd like a userstep to be created automatically when ever a user clicks to view a step.  This will allow the admin to know which steps have been viewed by which user.  Hope this makes sense and please let me know if you still think the userstep is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I've figured it out.  I had to add a little bit more, and I've given you the answer.  I'll also add the working version in another update.  Now I just have to figure out how to add a userstep automatically based off a click.